# NoSuchElementException when scraping website with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape player names & positions from this url: https://thedraftnetwork.com/articles/2021-nfl-draft-big-board-marino

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://thedraftnetwork.com/articles/2021-nfl-draft-big-board-marino')
p_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="player-name-event name gold-fade"]')
p_element.text
```

The error message I receive:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find
> element with xpath '//*[@class="player-name-event name
> gold-fade"]'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Content-Length":"132","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:51897","User-Agent":"selenium/3.141.0
> (python
> windows)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{"using":
> "xpath", "value": "//*[@class=\"player-name-event name
> gold-fade\"]", "sessionId":
> "ece0eb30-a916-11eb-95db-d1d816c61299"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/ece0eb30-a916-11eb-95db-d1d816c61299/element"}}
> Screenshot: available via screen

I know that this class exists (player-name-event name gold-fade), yet the error message states it can't find it. There is also another class called "player-info" and again Selenium can't find it. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I would check if the page is loaded when you are looking for the element. Try putting a 5 second wait right after the driver.get, and see if it works

Comment: I waited 50 seconds and received the same error message. Code that was added: driver.implicitly_wait(50)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code snippet:

```
driver.get('https://thedraftnetwork.com/articles/2021-nfl-draft-big-board-marino')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
players = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h4.player-name-event.name.gold-fade')))
positions = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.editorial')))

for player, position in zip(players, positions):
    print(player.text +" " +position.text)
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer. I received a different error this time: 

TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 0):

Just get it from the api:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

s = requests.Session()
s.get('https://thedraftnetwork.com/')
url = 'https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/classes/BigBoard'
headers = {
'accept': '*/*',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8',
'content-length': '279',
'content-type': 'text/plain',
'origin': 'https://thedraftnetwork.com',
'referer': 'https://thedraftnetwork.com/',
'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'}
payload = '''{"where":{"objectId":"6YRF5b8Y8e"},"include":"picks,picks.player,picks.player.collegeTeam","limit":1,"_method":"GET","_ApplicationId":"the-draft-network","_JavaScriptKey":"OBv0uezmNiZ2DUuz4Chk","_ClientVersion":"js2.15.0","_InstallationId":"6089d72c-1dd9-4f07-90de-1ef897ed1318"}'''

jsonData = s.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
picks = jsonData['results'][0]['picks']

df = pd.json_normalize(picks).sort_values('pickPosition').reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.head(10).to_string())

Output from spyder call 'get_namespace_view':
      objectId  pickPosition                  editorialReview                 createdAt                 updatedAt  __type className player.objectId player.collegeTeam.objectId player.collegeTeam.school player.collegeTeam.name                                                    player.collegeTeam.logoUrl  player.collegeTeam.sportsDataId player.collegeTeam.conference player.collegeTeam.shortDisplayName player.collegeTeam.slug player.collegeTeam.ourLadsName player.collegeTeam.tdnName player.collegeTeam.createdAt player.collegeTeam.updatedAt player.collegeTeam.__type player.collegeTeam.className player.draftYear player.height player.highschoolStats       player.name player.position player.weight player.year player.dateOfBirth      player.slug  player.school          player.createdAt          player.updatedAt                                                                   player.analyses  player.featuredImage player.image.__type                                     player.image.name                                                                                                      player.image.url player.jerseyNumber player.playerMatch.__type player.playerMatch.className player.__type player.className player.highSchool         player.conference player.featuredImage.__type                                       player.featuredImage.name                                                                                                      player.featuredImage.url  player.image player.ourLadsName player.collegeStats
57  nSvC9hokSg             1  <p>Final Grade: 94.00 / 100</p>  2021-04-22T19:28:09.350Z  2021-04-22T19:28:09.350Z  Object      Pick      KEAwwL73zW                  FEXHZnJnWJ                   Clemson                  Tigers   https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/static.fantasydata.com/logos/ncaa/27.png                         50000027     Atlantic Coast - Atlantic                                CLEM                 clemson                 Clemson Tigers                    Clemson     2019-07-26T22:41:00.004Z     2019-07-26T22:41:00.004Z                    Object                  CollegeTeam             2021          6'6"         5-star recruit   Trevor Lawrence              QB       220 lbs      Junior         10/06/1999  trevor-lawrence        Clemson  2020-04-17T21:05:58.198Z  2020-12-31T18:28:55.709Z  [{'__type': 'Pointer', 'className': 'PlayerAnalysis', 'objectId': 'VxMuexuSKt'}]                   NaN                File  c409766d6560d54ae063a53a358d4f77_Trevor Lawrence.png  https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/c409766d6560d54ae063a53a358d4f77_Trevor%20Lawrence.png                None                  Relation                       Player        Object           Player               NaN                       NaN                        File   c466aea5fdc42dfb955c3cd0e9458b65_TDN-FeaturedImage-3x2__1.jpg   https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/c466aea5fdc42dfb955c3cd0e9458b65_TDN-FeaturedImage-3x2__1.jpg           NaN                NaN                 NaN
23  ZKQxFpHEX9             2  <p>Final Grade: 93.00 / 100</p>  2021-04-22T19:28:09.333Z  2021-04-22T19:28:09.333Z  Object      Pick      R2fSJ5V9IZ                  PXUTCKJdCA                    Oregon                   Ducks  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/static.fantasydata.com/logos/ncaa/245.png                         50000245                Pac-12 - North                              OREGON                  oregon                   Oregon Ducks                     Oregon     2019-07-26T22:42:51.439Z     2019-07-26T22:42:51.439Z                    Object                  CollegeTeam             2021          6'5"         4-star recruit    Penei Sewell                OT       325 lbs      Junior         10/09/2000     penei-sewell         Oregon  2020-04-22T22:14:50.965Z  2020-12-31T19:16:02.346Z  [{'__type': 'Pointer', 'className': 'PlayerAnalysis', 'objectId': 'GoLA2yogOK'}]                   NaN                File     bd12a6584f0ebbaef2c263a5a1ee8a78_Penei Sewell.png     https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/bd12a6584f0ebbaef2c263a5a1ee8a78_Penei%20Sewell.png                None                  Relation                       Player        Object           Player               NaN                       NaN                        File   4d6fb86f63a0725c42bc5362afaf0d8c_TDN-FeaturedImage-3x2__2.jpg   https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/4d6fb86f63a0725c42bc5362afaf0d8c_TDN-FeaturedImage-3x2__2.jpg           NaN                NaN                 NaN
47  vAfcOLpH2J             3  <p>Final Grade: 92.50 / 100</p>  2021-04-22T19:28:09.350Z  2021-04-22T19:28:09.350Z  Object      Pick      SZFJcdG3nL                  5PxoN5ziAz                   Florida                  Gators  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/static.fantasydata.com/logos/ncaa/271.png                         50000271                    SEC - East                                 UFL                 florida                 Florida Gators                    Florida     2019-07-26T22:43:09.010Z     2019-07-26T22:43:09.010Z                    Object                  CollegeTeam             2021          6'5"         4-star recruit     Kyle Pitts                 TE       239 lbs      Junior                          kyle-pitts        Florida  2020-04-22T22:54:42.521Z  2020-12-31T18:52:43.365Z  [{'__type': 'Pointer', 'className': 'PlayerAnalysis', 'objectId': 'CuiHkn3Q2h'}]                   NaN                File       1cb027bcd7c4bfe09126f15a99beb874_Kyle Pitts.png       https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/1cb027bcd7c4bfe09126f15a99beb874_Kyle%20Pitts.png                None                  Relation                       Player        Object           Player               NaN                       NaN                        File  c5571dfbabfda2eebcc030df950128f5_TDN-FeaturedImage-3x2__11.jpg  https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/c5571dfbabfda2eebcc030df950128f5_TDN-FeaturedImage-3x2__11.jpg           NaN                NaN                 NaN
0   MniaCcCb1Y             4  <p>Final Grade: 92.00 / 100</p>  2021-04-22T19:28:09.315Z  2021-04-22T19:28:09.315Z  Object      Pick      gmqrK85AUP                  BXMxcTnllS                   Alabama            Crimson Tide  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/static.fantasydata.com/logos/ncaa/275.png                         50000275                    SEC - West                                 ALA                 alabama           Alabama Crimson Tide                    Alabama     2019-07-26T22:43:12.230Z     2019-07-26T22:43:12.230Z                    Object                  CollegeTeam             2021         5'10"         4-star recruit   Jaylen Waddle                WR       182 lbs      Junior                       jaylen-waddle        Alabama  2020-04-22T22:58:45.599Z  2021-01-05T14:39:06.697Z  [{'__type': 'Pointer', 'className': 'PlayerAnalysis', 'objectId': '4AlB2vRwSl'}]                   NaN                File    f969cc2594ffc82b49022a9dd403a35b_Jaylen Waddle.png    https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/f969cc2594ffc82b49022a9dd403a35b_Jaylen%20Waddle.png                None                  Relation                       Player        Object           Player               NaN                       NaN                         NaN                                                             NaN                                                                                                                           NaN           NaN                NaN                 NaN
55  Tz2wsZgaEB             5  <p>Final Grade: 90.00 / 100</p>  2021-04-22T19:28:09.347Z  2021-04-22T19:28:09.347Z  Object      Pick      SDOMHXqIQp                  7t5H4RpD0i                       LSU                  Tigers  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/static.fantasydata.com/logos/ncaa/269.png                         50000269                    SEC - West                                 LSU                     lsu                     LSU Tigers                        LSU     2019-07-26T22:43:07.540Z     2019-07-26T22:43:07.540Z                    Object                  CollegeTeam             2021          6'1"         4-star recruit   Ja'Marr Chase                WR       208 lbs      Junior         03/01/2000     jamarr-chase            LSU  2020-04-22T22:57:16.625Z  2020-12-31T18:31:38.799Z  [{'__type': 'Pointer', 'className': 'PlayerAnalysis', 'objectId': 'dJXQUftMVk'}]                   NaN                File   e97294429e533d6d78f7d4e8e09abe15_Chase Claypool.PNG   https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/e97294429e533d6d78f7d4e8e09abe15_Chase%20Claypool.PNG                None                  Relation                       Player        Object           Player               NaN                       NaN                        File   245f8056f57f98461710df480e0d627e_TDN-FeaturedImage-3x2__3.jpg   https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/245f8056f57f98461710df480e0d627e_TDN-FeaturedImage-3x2__3.jpg           NaN                NaN                 NaN
7   sdSaBnzBGh             6  <p>Final Grade: 89.50 / 100</p>  2021-04-22T19:28:09.363Z  2021-04-22T19:28:09.363Z  Object      Pick      0mSBgLCNXv                  o0tGvEgAHr                Ohio State                Buckeyes   https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/static.fantasydata.com/logos/ncaa/98.png                         50000098                Big Ten - East                                 OSU              ohio-state            Ohio State Buckeyes                 Ohio State     2019-07-26T22:41:34.608Z     2019-07-26T22:41:34.608Z                    Object                  CollegeTeam             2021          6'3"         5-star recruit     Justin Fields              QB       223 lbs      Junior         03/05/1999    justin-fields     Ohio State  2020-04-21T17:42:27.056Z  2020-12-20T16:13:41.704Z  [{'__type': 'Pointer', 'className': 'PlayerAnalysis', 'objectId': 'jCNzEqDwxk'}]                   NaN                File    e4f19085a7b586d55262ea1affc961bf_Justin Fields.png    https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/e4f19085a7b586d55262ea1affc961bf_Justin%20Fields.png                   1                  Relation                       Player        Object           Player               NaN                       NaN                        File   c45e99461d035624a45379368b7b491b_TDN-FeaturedImage-3x2__4.jpg   https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/c45e99461d035624a45379368b7b491b_TDN-FeaturedImage-3x2__4.jpg           NaN                NaN                 NaN
51  17hkC7PIjk             7  <p>Final Grade: 89.02 / 100</p>  2021-04-22T19:28:09.374Z  2021-04-22T19:28:09.374Z  Object      Pick      EjpZ4YtzI0                  6pvjvEq470                       BYU                 Cougars  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/static.fantasydata.com/logos/ncaa/336.png                         50000336              FBS Independents                                 BYU                     byu                    BYU Cougars                        BYU     2019-07-26T22:43:51.073Z     2019-07-26T22:43:51.073Z                    Object                  CollegeTeam             2021          6'3"                   None       Zach Wilson              QB       210 lbs      Junior                         zach-wilson            BYU  2020-06-13T11:14:19.831Z  2021-01-05T14:34:11.409Z  [{'__type': 'Pointer', 'className': 'PlayerAnalysis', 'objectId': 'VcxDPxplrM'}]                   NaN                File           e31007f3497cac69538f687990ce0a65_Wilson.JPG             https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/e31007f3497cac69538f687990ce0a65_Wilson.JPG                None                  Relation                       Player        Object           Player               NaN                       NaN                         NaN                                                             NaN                                                                                                                           NaN           NaN                NaN                 NaN
11  QgaKc0JC2n             8  <p>Final Grade: 89.00 / 100</p>  2021-04-22T19:28:09.372Z  2021-04-22T19:28:09.372Z  Object      Pick      NKA9vgu5S8                  t0ClOyak0N             Virginia Tech                  Hokies   https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/static.fantasydata.com/logos/ncaa/31.png                         50000031      Atlantic Coast - Coastal                               VTECH           virginia-tech           Virginia Tech Hokies              Virginia Tech     2019-07-26T22:41:03.789Z     2019-07-26T22:41:03.789Z                    Object                  CollegeTeam             2021          6'2"                   None      Caleb Farley              CB       197 lbs   RS Junior         11/02/1998     caleb-farley  Virginia Tech  2019-07-27T01:19:38.823Z  2021-01-05T14:30:20.936Z  [{'__type': 'Pointer', 'className': 'PlayerAnalysis', 'objectId': 'jHbxDweRAX'}]                   NaN                File     254ac6fa059278663cb171e6c46e6dc7_Caleb Farley.png     https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/254ac6fa059278663cb171e6c46e6dc7_Caleb%20Farley.png                   3                  Relation                       Player        Object           Player            Maiden  Atlantic Coast - Coastal                         NaN                                                             NaN                                                                                                                           NaN           NaN                NaN                 NaN
24  oHFu4Ds6Gb             9  <p>Final Grade: 88.00 / 100</p>  2021-04-22T19:28:09.376Z  2021-04-22T19:28:09.376Z  Object      Pick      1pKUn4IfC4                  S6HQBGhYej              Northwestern                Wildcats  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/static.fantasydata.com/logos/ncaa/100.png                         50000100                Big Ten - West                                 NWU            northwestern          Northwestern Wildcats               Northwestern     2019-07-26T22:41:36.490Z     2019-07-26T22:41:36.490Z                    Object                  CollegeTeam             2021          6'4"         3-star recruit    Rashawn Slater              OT       315 lbs      Senior                      rashawn-slater   Northwestern  2020-04-29T13:50:52.192Z  2021-01-05T14:44:40.745Z  [{'__type': 'Pointer', 'className': 'PlayerAnalysis', 'objectId': 'ig2TEpdipx'}]                   NaN                File           18c2861114e0945e8f20933bd4d3fdcf_Slater.JPG             https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/18c2861114e0945e8f20933bd4d3fdcf_Slater.JPG                None                  Relation                       Player        Object           Player               NaN                       NaN                         NaN                                                             NaN                                                                                                                           NaN           NaN                NaN                 NaN
74  ke7Gynui5r            10  <p>Final Grade: 87.50 / 100</p>  2021-04-22T19:28:09.435Z  2021-04-22T19:28:09.435Z  Object      Pick      fm74W3OByo                  2AGpCcpgFf                Penn State           Nittany Lions  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/static.fantasydata.com/logos/ncaa/101.png                         50000101                Big Ten - East                                 PSU              penn-state       Penn State Nittany Lions                 Penn State     2019-07-26T22:41:37.362Z     2019-07-26T22:41:37.362Z                    Object                  CollegeTeam             2021          6'2"         5-star recruit  Micah Parsons                 LB       245 lbs      Junior         05/26/1999    micah-parsons     Penn State  2020-04-22T21:50:24.520Z  2020-12-18T21:56:58.016Z  [{'__type': 'Pointer', 'className': 'PlayerAnalysis', 'objectId': 'dWmm2BfE8E'}]                   NaN                File    3f5cffd4dbada1c0e83997285c240b10_Micah Parsons.png    https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/3f5cffd4dbada1c0e83997285c240b10_Micah%20Parsons.png                  11                  Relation                       Player        Object           Player               NaN                       NaN                        File   c5624e14eda2def4f52cae4bbeb7c0ee_TDN-FeaturedImage-3x2__7.jpg   https://apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com/api/files/the-draft-network/c5624e14eda2def4f52cae4bbeb7c0ee_TDN-FeaturedImage-3x2__7.jpg           NaN                NaN                 NaN
```

Comment: Wow! I searched google for an API solution before working with Selenium... I couldn't find find anything. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: When I go to the endpoint I get a message I'm not authorized. Any idea how to get authorization? Again, not finding much with a google search.

Comment: might have to change the payload. I'll ahve to look at it tomorrow

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the help.

Comment: What do you mean when you go to the endpoint? You mean in the browser?

Comment: Yes, in the browser. I also ran the code and got an error: SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='apiv2.thedraftnetwork.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/classes/BigBoard (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)')))

Comment: Well this is a POST request. It won’t work by just inputing into the browser. It needs to send the query parameters with it. As far as the error, you might be getting blocked because you may be hitting the server to many times in too short of time.

Comment: I submitted the code once, so hitting the server too many times can't be the reason.